# animating sprites smoother movements fiddle jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to animate this facebook sticker, this is an sprite of 10 images. this is based on the background position in css.

In the facebook animation the movements are nice and smooth, I just got square weird movements...
what am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/64nu4h4w/37/

```js
var currentY = 0;
var isAnimating = false;
var $window = $('.window');
var windowWidth = 80;
var frameRateMs = 100;

function updateWindow() {
    if (isAnimating) {
        $window.css({'background-position-y': currentY + 'px'});
        currentY -= windowWidth;
        if (currentY == -windowWidth*4) {
            windowWidth = -windowWidth;
        } else if (currentY == 0) {
            windowWidth =windowWidth;
        }
    }
    setTimeout(updateWindow, frameRateMs);
}

isAnimating = true;

updateWindow();
```

```css
h1 {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
.window {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: url("https://scontent.flim5-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.1997-6/p240x240/10333108_451580824986023_868823540_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=2b81c371938ee4f2648f4e35fe260b33&oe=5B75B854");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Current State using .animate() (hover for effect)</h1>
<div class="window"></div>


<h1>Sprites:</h1>
<img src="https://scontent.flim5-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.1997-6/p240x240/10333108_451580824986023_868823540_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=2b81c371938ee4f2648f4e35fe260b33&oe=5B75B854"/>
```

Comment: Looks like you only get the first and the last image.

Comment: yes  realised I'm just changing the y position,, not the x, i cant figure out how

Comment: This is an improvemnt, adding x ovement but still is aweful http://jsfiddle.net/64nu4h4w/39/

Comment: Really looks like an improvement.

Comment: in what order do you expect frames to show up during the animation?

Comment: left to right, top to bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put [numbers for each frame](http://jsfiddle.net/hhr2mwxe/) on the image to find out what happened as I suspected order was incorrect. Then I've amended the code to shift frames left-right, top-bottom. Also added a variable for the total number of frames in order to skip empty frames.

```js
var currentY = 0;
var currentX = 0;
var isAnimating = false;
var $window = $('.window');
var windowWidth = 80;
var frameRateMs = 170;
var totalNumberOfFrames = 10;
var currentFrame = 1;

function updateWindow() {
  if (isAnimating) {
    $window.css({
      'background-position': currentX + 'px ' + currentY + "px"
    });
    if (currentFrame == totalNumberOfFrames) {
      currentX = 0;
      currentY = 0;
    } else if (currentX > -windowWidth * 3) {
      currentX -= windowWidth; 
    } else {
      currentY -= windowWidth; 
      currentX = 0;  
    }
    currentFrame = currentFrame < totalNumberOfFrames ? currentFrame + 1 : 1;
  }
  setTimeout(updateWindow, frameRateMs);
}
$window.hover(function() {
  isAnimating = true;
}, function() {
  isAnimating = false;
});
updateWindow();
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.window {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: url("https://scontent.flim5-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.1997-6/p240x240/10333108_451580824986023_868823540_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=2b81c371938ee4f2648f4e35fe260b33&oe=5B75B854");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Desired Effect:</h1>
<img src="https://scontent.flim5-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.1997-6/p240x240/10333108_451580824986023_868823540_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=2b81c371938ee4f2648f4e35fe260b33&oe=5B75B854" />

<h1>Current State using .animate() (hover for effect)</h1>
<div class="window"></div>
```

Comment: pretty awesome approach....I'm into removing those two emty frames `number 11 & 12`, how would be possible to remove them?

Comment: if you tell Javascript how many frames you have, then in the code you can ignore last empty frames by just initilising x and y when it comes to last frame.

Comment: @Dan, I put the original image now and skipped empty frames. Looks great now!

Comment: Hey, I have this new question, If you could check it, would be great https://stackoverflow.com/q/49848122/9503467 thank you